# Automatically Replacing Text to Clean Data

Tags: csv, text, macros, lookup-tables, xlsm

I would like a way to replace all different names for a country and replace them with one name to make future pivot tables more effective.

For example: If the country column has a bunch of different rows containing 
GBR, GB, UK, United Kingdom, etc.

I want to change them all to United Kingdom without having to manually filter them and change them. Is there a way to make a table and then let excel do the rest of the work?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide some sample data and the codes that you already tried so that we are better able to help you. Also what program do you use. If you use excel please refrain from using macros tag and use [excel-vba] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks. I made two lookup tables and used them while recording the macro. Maybe it can be a little cleaner, but I just recorded this:

Sub Country_Region_Names()
'
' Country_Region_Names Macro
'
    Range("Y1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "-"
    Range("Y1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y1:BA1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("Y1:BA1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-2
    Range("BB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NewCountry"
    Range("BB2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-35],'Country Lookup Table'!R[2]C[-52]:R[228]C[-51],2,0),"""")"
    Range("BB2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BB2:BB1045"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("BB2:BB1045").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1172
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-34
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-2
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=8
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=3
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=11
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-368
    Range("BB2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-35],'Country Lookup Table'!R4C2:R230C3,2,0),"""")"
    Range("BB2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BB2:BB1045")
    Range("BB2:BB1045").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=933
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1069
    Range("BC1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Region"
    Range("BC2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("BB2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("BC2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Country Lookup Table'!R4C5:R230C6,2,0),"""")"
    Range("BC2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BC2:BC256")
    Range("BC2:BC256").Select
End Sub